# "Could not find activesupport in any of the sources," even though activesupport is installed.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, activesupport

When I try to do `rails server` and `thin start`, both say: "Could not find activesupport-3.0.6 in any of the sources."

I have activesupport-3.0.7 installed. Do I need to revert so that activesupport matches my Rails version (3.0.6)?

Comment: This question applies regardless of whether activesupport and Rails are the same version, and seems to occur throughout the 3.x.x series, according to Google searches. It happens to me with 3.1.1, for example.

Answer (score 9):

Run `bundle install` in your rails directory (or change your Gemfile to require 3.0.7 instead of 3.0.6)

Also, when running the `rails` commands, you can prefix it with `bundle exec` to make sure it's using the correct version:

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Comment: Prefixing `rails` with `bundle exec` is not needed, because `rails` makes sure to load the correct version by itself. All other commands, however, must be prefixed by `bundle exec` (for example, `bundle exec rake`).

Comment: @Dimitar, I actually couldn't get it to work without `bundle exec`. I'm using rails 3.1.1.

Comment: @mohawkjohn, good point. I should clarify—if you have older versions of Rails installed, e.g. Rails 2.x, which does not speak "Bundler", then you indeed need to use `bundle exec rails` instead of simply `rails`.

If you only have Rails 3+ installed, it will work, because from 3.0.0 onward, Rails understands Bundler. Better make it a habit and/or a shell alias to always write `bundle exec`, though.

Comment: @Dimitar, I think it may be because I upgraded to Rails 3 from Rails 2. But that's just a guess. I'm definitely using 3. =)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your `Gemfile` and your installed gems are out-of-sync:

1. Which version of Rails is listed in your `Gemfile`—3.0.6 or 3.0.7?
2. Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, I have run bundle install.

Gemfile of the skeleton i'm trying to run is 3.0.6...should i change it?

Comment: I tried changing it to 3.0.7 but then it says cannot find Could not find sqlite3-1.3.3 in any of the sources...how do I sync everything up? (sorry i'm super noob)